# Error in installing unity-tweak-tool

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

I cannot install unity-tweak-tool. When ever i try to install through software center is shows installing and suddenly changes to install.

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide the screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you didn't use apt correctly.

First, remove unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-tweak-tool
```

Then, install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```